# Select python data-frame columns with similar names

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, subset

I have a data frame named df1 like this:

```
as_id   TCGA_AF_2687    TCGA_AF_2689_Norm   TCGA_AF_2690    TCGA_AF_2691_Norm   
   31      1                  5                  9                 2
```

I wanna select all the columns which end with "Norm", I have tried the code down below

```
import os;
print os.getcwd()
os.chdir('E:/task')
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_table('haha.txt')
Norms = []
for s in df1.columns:
    if s.endswith('Norm'):
        Norms.append(s)
print Norms
```

but I only get a list of names. what can I do to select all the columns including their values rather than just the columns names? I know it may be a silly question, but I am a new beginner, really need someone to help, thank you so much for your kindness and your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df1[Norms]` will get the actual columns from `df1`.

As a matter of fact the whole code can be simplified to

```
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('E:/task')
df1 = pd.read_table('haha.txt')
norm_df = df1[[column for column in df1.columns if column.endswith('Norm')]]
```

Comment: You dont need a list comprehension if you use `.str` accessor i.e  `df1[df1.columns[df1.columns.str.endswith('Norm')]]` Or `df1.iloc[:,df1.columns.str.endswith('Norm')]`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use the `filter` higher-order function:

```
newdf = df[list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith("Norm"),df.columns))]
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
   TCGA_AF_2689_Norm  TCGA_AF_2691_Norm
0                  5                  2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is really great.